# Java Jsoup Print For Loop

Tags: java, html, list, for-loop, jsoup

I'm new to Java as well as Jsoup. I have successfully been able to scrape website data with Jsoup. However, currently I am printing the search result title's and they are all returning on one line. I'd like to nest the results in a for loop so that the search title results print on one line each.

```
This is how the website is formatted:
<ul>
<li><span class ="title">Title 1<span></li>
<li><span class ="title">Title 2<span></li>
<li><span class ="title">Title 3<span></li>
</ul>
```

My code is returning: Title 1 Title 2 Title 3

```
My Java code:
public class WebScrape {

        public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {

            final Document document = Jsoup.connect("website.com").get();

            String searchResultsTitle = document.select("span[class=title]").text();
            System.out.println(searchResultsTitle);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Document.select` returns `org.jsoup.select.Elements`, each `Element` being one `span` with `class=title`, so instead of calling `.text()` you can store the titles inside `Elements` and iterate through them.

```
Elements titles = document.select("span[class=title]");

for(Element title : titles) {
   System.out.println(title.text());            
}
```